# How to read receive sms without permission in Android

Tags: android, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

In some applications i see read **receive SMS** for get active code!
But for read this message not allowed any **permission**!
My android version is **28** and i know in **23** or above for read messages we get **runtime permission** from users!
In this application how to get read message **without any permission**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your query seems similar to [this question](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview), in which case it is the [SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview).

> With the SMS Retriever API, you can perform SMS-based user verification in your Android app automatically, without requiring the user to manually type verification codes, and without requiring any extra app permissions.